# db2prereqcheck hangs on some linux systems

Tags: db2, rhel, db2-luw, rhel8

When doing a `db2prereqcheck` on a linx system, it hangs and doesn't ever come back.

The `db2prereqcheck` command is not only executed manually when one wants to install db2 components. It is also called by some diagnostic tests like `db2support . -s` for example.

I experienced that it can hang and I had other change but killing the process.

What can be a reason for this?

Comment: collecting db2pd -stacks, and db2fodc -hang full will be more helpful to identify the issue

Answer (score 1):

We disovered that if the environment variable `LANG` is set to `C.UTF-8`, which is default, db2prereqchek does not work.

We changed it to en_EN.UTF-8 and that made the trick.

Therefore, for user db2inst1, we added following to the `.bashrc` file, to have it permanent for that user:

```
LANG=en_EN.UTF-8 export LANG
LC_ALL=en_EN.utf-8 export LC_ALL
```